# html/css select last-child of last-child for ul/li

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I've got a `<ul> <li>` structure, what I want to do is something like

`.div ul:last-child li:last-child {border-bottom:1px etc}`,

so it would select the last `<li>` from the last `<ul>`.

```
<div id="accord_wrapper">
        <div class="accordionButton"></div>
            <div class="accordionContent">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="http://www.google.com">one</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.yahoo.com">two</a></li>
                </ul>
        </div>          
        <div class="accordionButton">Button 2 Content</div>
        <div class="accordionContent"><ul>
                    <li><a href="http://www.google.com">one</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.yahoo.com">two</a></li>
                </ul></div>
        <div class="accordionButton">Button 3 Content</div>
        <div class="accordionContent"><ul>
                    <li><a href="http://www.google.com">one</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.yahh.com">two</a></li>
                </ul></div>
        <div class="accordionButton">Button 4 Content</div>
        <div class="accordionContent"><ul>
                    <li><a href="http://www.google.com">one</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">two</a></li>
                </ul></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You're missing an element with class `div`.

Comment: that is just example code.

Comment: Other than the missing `.div` ancestor element, it looks like it works to me:  http://jsfiddle.net/BFrkK/

Comment: what I want to do is something like

.div ul:last-child li:last-child {border-bottom:1px etc},

so it would select the last <li> from the last <ul>.

Comment: yeah, what you have is correct. you just need to wrap your html in <div class="div">what you have already</div>

Comment: @user2118228 I think you don't want the class selector `.div` but the tag selector `div` (without `.` in front)

Comment: Just a note, [IE8 and less doesn't support the `:last-child` selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/:last-child).

Comment: for some reason it is selecting the last `<li>` of every `<ul>`
I see it works in jsfiddle, but not for me

Comment: When you say "select the last div", what do you intend to do with it? Just style, or something else that may require JavaScript?

Comment: @user2118228: Then you're going to have to provide actual code and not "just example code".

Comment: i need to select the last `<li>` of the last `<ul>` so i can add a bottom border to it, it's part of a jquery accordion nav

Comment: Ok, I've added my exact code. If you run it in js fiddle it selects every last `<li>`, not just the last `<li`> of the last `<ul>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your actual code, each `ul` is the last and only child of its parent `div.accordionContent`. That's why every `ul` is being matched by your selector.

Since the last `div.accordionContent` happens to also be the last child of your top-level element, you should be able to do this instead:

```
#accord_wrapper .accordionContent:last-child ul li:last-child
```

Answer (score 3):

`:last-child` pseudo selector is from CSS3, so your browser needs to be compatible in order to use it. See http://caniuse.com/#search=%3Alast-child

By the way, `.div ul:last-child li:last-child {border-bottom:1px etc}` works as you described.

Answer (score 0):

You can select any li inside your ul by using `:nth-child(number)`

Here's an example

html:

```
<ul>

     <li>one</li>
     <li>two</li>
     <li>three</li>
     <li>four</li>
     <li>five</li>

</ul>
```

let's say we want to select the third child inside ul, then we would use nth-child(3)

css:

```
ul:last-child li:nth-child(3) {
    /*style something*/
}
```

Comment: But how to select the last one?